# Use FCM and GCM for different APIs

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to use FCM and GCM in the same app but for different API numbers?

I mean something like this in manifest:

```
// if api >= 21 
<service
android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
.
.
</service>

// if api < 21 
<service
android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
.
.
</service>
```

Comment: What's FBC?  Do you mean Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

Comment: why would you do that ?

Comment: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/time-to-upgrade-from-gcm-to-fcm.html

Answer (score 1):

No, according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) gcm and fcm cannot coexist in the same application.

Furthermore, gcm is deprecated for quite a while and will definitely be shut down in April 2019. So I strongly suggest migrating to fcm. Migration from gcm to fcm is quite easy using the guide linked.

Additionally, gcm does not work on applications compiled with a target framework of oreo or higher. That's a permission restriction with background services. But with Google's latest playstore policy, you must compile targeting (target version, non miversion!) at least the last API version before the current if you want to upload your app to the playstore. This also applies for updates of existing apps.

There's a hacky workaround for the permission issue, but with gcm being shut down in a few months, it's not worth the effort.